# Selenium unable to discover open pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using web scraping for my project and it has worked perfectly on a windows system. Deploying it on ubuntu has worked perfectly the first time running my script but any time after that I receive the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
```

Usually before this happens the script has no output for around a minute and 30 seconds before returning the error. Any help would be appreciated!

My code:

```
import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

for i in range(5):
    URLS = []
    URLS.append('https://website.com/')

for i in range(1):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080")
        options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
        options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./drivers/chromedriver", options=options)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)

        for url in URLS:
            try:
                webdriver.get(url)

                innerHTML = webdriver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, "html.parser")

                for i in soup.select("#ELEMENT"):
                    global ELEMENT
                    ELEMENT = i.text
                    print(ELEMENT)

                webdriver.close()
                webdriver.quit()
           

            except:
                pass
```

Comment: Not sure, but possibly you are using an outdated version of `ChromeDriver`.

Comment: I'm using the most up-to-date chromedriver

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29513586)

Comment: Why do you have this loop `for i in range(1):` ? Also can you share `innerHTML = webdriver.page_source` entire page_resource ?

Comment: for i in range is temporary as I am going to add in a try except later... innerHTML is just html from the website which allows me to select an element. I don't think either item is preventing the code from functioning as far as I know

Comment: no i meant to ask if you share page resource here with us, also make sure to use @ while replying

Comment: I don't think the page is causing the error... its the way the webdriver interacts with the chromium browser that is causing the issue @cruisepandey

Comment: 1) Comment out lines 19,22
2) replace "webdriver" with "driver" in lines 26,28,36,37
3) replace "#ELEMENT" with "body" on line 31
4) replace line 21 with: driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=test.log"])
Does it work?

Comment: The code is not giving an error and executing the code it can. However it cannot find any of the elements I provide it and give me the info I need

Comment: What element(s) are you looking for on this page?

Comment: If you look at the HTML code of this webpage, there is no occurrence of "#ELEMENT", So, it can't find it.

Comment: What are the URLS in this list `URLS = []`?  This information is needed, because you haven't provided enough details to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Specific tags that appear on the website were replaced in the #ELEMENT tag. I can't say which websites I am using but the tags do appear on the website and should provide a result. I think it is a chromedriver/selenium issue

Comment: Can't you find an example on another website which is not top-secret?

Comment: even trying https://google.com and attempting to print the body does not work @S_Bersier

Comment: Did you inspect the "test.log" file? (cf. modification on line 21). Any indication in it?

Comment: What OS are you using? What version? Chromium version? Selenium version? How did you install chromedriver? Python version?

Comment: My infos: Ubuntu 20.04 // Chromium 92.0.4515.131 snap //  chromium-chromedriver 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 // python 3.8.10 // Selenium 3.141.0 // beautifulsoup bs4-0.0.1

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 // Chromium 92.0.4515.131 // Chromedriver 92.0.4515.131 // Selenium 3.141.0

Comment: I could not find the test.log file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235736/discussion-between-s-bersier-and-python-123).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **scrape** restricted or blocked website you have to use random user agents. You can check below code snippet. Hope it should work for you.

```
import random
import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


for i in range(5):
    URLS = []
    URLS.append('https://google.com/')

for i in range(1):
    user_agent_list = [
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11.5; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_5_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
    ]
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)

    browser_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    browser_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    browser_options.add_argument("--headless")
    browser_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    browser_options.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080")
    browser_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
    browser_options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
    browser_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    browser_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=browser_options, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=test.log"])

    for url in URLS:
        try:
            web_driver.get(url)

            innerHTML = web_driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, "html.parser")

            for i in soup.select("body"):
                global ELEMENT
                ELEMENT = i.text
                print(ELEMENT)

            web_driver.close()
            web_driver.quit()
       

        except:
            pass
```

Please let me know it it's not worked.